# sub make with foreach fails randomly (with higher J factor)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using GNU `make`, where I have a top level `makefile`, which invokes
another `makefile`, for different types of builds, like:

```
LIST_OF_TYPES: 32 64 ...

tgt-name: deps
          $(foreach i,$(LIST_OF_TYPES), \
            $(MAKE) -f $(MY_MAKEFILE) ARCH=$i mylib;)
```

when running with higher `j` factor like `-j100` etc, one of the build fails, but
the return value is still `0` so, I cannot make out if the build really did work!
Is there anything wrong with the way I'm using the `foreach` construct?
or its just the higher `j` with `foreach` which is causing problems?

Comment: I take it you are using a shell other than bash. How does the sub-build fail? How do you know it fails? This loop calls Make sequentially, so why are you using a high `j`? Because there some other set of targets that can be built in parallel?

Comment: @Beta, I am using `bash`, yea, I'm not sure why the sub-build fails when I run with high `j`, ; later if I run again, I see that the build succeeds. Yes, there are many other targets which take time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen this kind of use of `foreach`, but it seems to work for you. Usually I use a `bash` for loop

```
tgt-name: deps
    for i in $(LIST_OF_TYPES); do $(MAKE) -f $(MY_MAKEFILE) ARCH=$$i mylib; done
```

But this is not the problem, since in either case the `make`s are run sequentially, AFAICS.

Since you build a library, there's the possible clash of two objects being inserted into an archive simultaneously. When this happens the archive might become corrupted.

As with every parallel execution, be it make jobs or threads, you must protect the shared resources (the archive in your case). You must add the objects at the end of the library build or protect the insertion with some lock (e.g. [`man lockfile`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lockfile) or similar).

There might be other problems, of course. Look out for the simultaneous access to shared resources (object files, archives, ...) or incomplete defined dependencies.

*Update*:

`foreach` seems *not* to be a problem. Set `LIST_OF_TYPES` to a single type (e.g. `32` only) and then do a `make -j100 mylib`. If the problem is with the building of a single archive, it will fail with only one type as well.

You can also test with `make ARCH=32 -j100 mylib`. This should show the problem too.

Comment: All my different builds are written to different directory hieararchy (build-tree), maybe I should try `bash`'s `for` loop instead of `make`s `for` loop

Comment: and BTW, I found this kind of use of `foreach` somewhere here on SO

Comment: @vyom Don't get me wrong, if it works, it's fine. There are many things, I haven't seen before.

Comment: @vyom Most likely, the foreach loop is not the problem, please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

The top-level makefile you have listed is safe under `-j` (though badly sub-optimal). After the expansion of the `$(foreach...)`, `make` effectively sees:

```
tgt-name: deps
    $(MAKE) -f $(MY_MAKEFILE) ARCH=32 mylib; $(MAKE) -f $(MY_MAKEFILE) ARCH=64 mylib; ...
```

When one of these sub-makes fails (due to mis-handling of `-j`), the failure is not reported to the top level make. You need to use something like:

```
tgt-name: deps
    $(MAKE) -f $(MY_MAKEFILE) ARCH=32 mylib && $(MAKE) -f $(MY_MAKEFILE) ARCH=64 mylib && ... && :
```

The `&&` tells bash to exit immediately with an error if the previous command fails. (The `:` at the end is the bash builtin that does nothing but issue a successful exit—it will simplify your writing of the `$(foreach ...)`.)

---

*EDIT:*

The proper way to this of course is to use make dependencies, not serial processing in the shell. You want *make* to see something like:

```
tgt-name: # default target

.PHONY: target-32
target-32: deps
    $(MAKE) -f ${MY_MAKEFILE} arch=32 mylib

.PHONY: target-64
target-64: deps
    $(MAKE) -f ${MY_MAKEFILE} arch=64 mylib

# etc. etc.

tgt-name: target-32 target-64
    @echo $@ Success
```

This is `-j` safe. Under `-j` *make* will make all of the `target-%` *at the same time*. Nice. (Though in this case it seems that your `$MY_MAKEFILE` is not `-j` safe (naughty!).) A few macros to replace the boiler plate:

```
LIST_OF_TYPES := 32 64 ...
LIST_OF_TARGETS := $(add-prefix,target-,${LIST_OF_TYPES})

tgt-name: # default target

.PHONY: ${LIST_OF_TARGETS}
${LIST_OF_TARGETS}: target-%: deps # Static Pattern Rule will (conveniently) set $*
    $(MAKE) -f ${MY_MAKEFILE} arch=$* mylib

tgt-name: ${LIST_OF_TARGETS}
    @echo $@ Success
```

P.S. I suspect that you should be marking *tgt-name* as `.PHONY`

Comment: As of now, I have `;` as the command separator, is there a way to add `&&` between the commands, but not in the end?, i.e in cases when I have more than 2 sub-makes

Comment: @vyom: It's a simple tweak. `$(foreach i,$(LIST_OF_TYPES),$(MAKE) -f $(MY_MAKEFILE) ARCH=$i mylib && ) :`. Notice that `:` at the end.